# Connect Qt to a Database

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, connection

I've been trying really hard for the past few hours to connect my Qt software to a MySQL database that I've hosted using a website that hosts small MySQL databases for free. I can connect to it using phpMyAdmin, but I'm really having trouble getting my software to connect to it.

This is the error message:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect".

Can somebody explain to me what this means, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to headers, libraries & client dll from MySQL
2. [Compile Qt/MySQL driver](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows)
3. Provide path to mysql client library in PATH environment